# Is it odd to have search results displayed in a way that is inconsistent with the rest of an app?

Tags: mobile, search, hierarchy

I've spent a few days thinking about how to layout my mobile app's interface and I think I've found a way that makes sense to me. I just need some advice to check that I'm not veering too far from best practices.

My app has the following hierarchy:

> Timers > Tasks

Each timer can have a static list of one to many tasks.

I contemplated displaying a single list of tasks with timer headers on just one screen, but there were over 100 tasks so it seemed like too many to scroll through (especially since I needed a way to configure individual timers). So I want to have three screens:

1. A timer screen that displays a list of timers
2. Tapping a timer will bring up the tasks screen which lists the names of all the tasks for that timer, and allows the user to configure settings for the timer
3. Tapping a task will bring up the task detail screen which displays more information about a task

However, I want to add search functionality at the timer screen level to find tasks.

My question is about whether it's okay to display different details about the tasks in the search results compared to any of the other 3 screens.

e.g.

1. The timer screen displays a name, time, number of tasks, and a notification on/off indicator
2. The tasks screen displays a name, and whether it has been completed
3. The task detail screen displays the time, name, whether it has been completed, a description, statistics, and other information.
4. **The search results on the timer screen show a task name, the time, and whether it has been completed.**

Does anything about this sound like bad UX? This is the first ever mobile app I've worked on, so the UX part has been especially hard to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search result screen is displaying the required information from the task screen (task name, completed?)  and task detail screen (time). 
It is good not to overload the user with information. I feel your approach is right.